# How to get icons showing in React Native Router Flux tab?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux

I'm building a react native (version 6.4.1) app using expo. I'm using react-native-router-flux as a navigator. For some reason I'm unable to get the tab icon to show.

Here is my code:

```
// Libraries and References
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Scene, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import I18n from './utils/i18n/i18n';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const Constants = require('./utils/constants/Constants');
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';


// Components
import homeScreen from './components/screens/HomeScreen';
import alertsScreen from './components/screens/AlertAnnouncementScreen';
import resoucesScreen from './components/screens/ResourceScreen';
import settingsScreen from './components/screens/AccountSettingsScreen';


class TabIcon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width:30, height:30 }}>
                <Icon style={{ color: 'red' }} name='md-checkmark-circle' />
            </View>
        );
    }
};


// Navigation 
class RouterComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Scene key="tabHolder" tabs swipeEnabled activeBackgroundColor={Constants.BGC_GREEN} inactiveBackgroundColor={Constants.BGC_BLUE} inactiveTintColor={Constants.TAB_GREY} activeTintColor='white' type={ActionConst.RESET} >
                        <Scene key="homeTab" initial component={homeScreen} title={I18n.t('titles.home')} hideNavBar icon={TabIcon}>

                        </Scene>
                        <Scene key="alertsTab" component={alertsScreen} title={I18n.t('titles.alerts')} hideNavBar navBarButtonColor='white' icon={({ focused }) => (<Icon name='bell' type='font-awesome' size={30} color={focused ? 'white' : Constants.TAB_GREY} />)} />
                        <Scene key="resourcesTab" component={resoucesScreen} title={I18n.t('titles.resources')} hideNavBar icon={({ focused }) => (<Ionicons name='info' type='font-awesome' size={30} color={focused ? 'white' : Constants.TAB_GREY} />)} />
                        <Scene key="settingsTab" component={settingsScreen} title={I18n.t('titles.settings')} hideNavBar icon={({ focused }) => (<Icon name='gear' type='font-awesome' color={focused ? 'white' : Constants.TAB_GREY} />)} />

                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}


//


// export
export default connect(null, null)(RouterComponent);
```

However, I still have no tabs. I've tried all the CSS aspects possible on this (hence why they're so full), to no avail. Any clues?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I know that it's a tab issue because this works in the home screen but not on the tabs:

Here is the home screen:

```
    <View>
    <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>This is a signed in user</Text>
    <Icon name="check-circle" size ={30} />
    </View>
```

Here is the tab logic I just updated:

```
class TabIcon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Icon name="check-circle" size ={30} />
        );
    }
};
```

Here is the screen shot :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to the GitHub for this, and was finally able to get an answer. [Here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3504) is the link.

The issue was the `navigationOptions`. It will over ride *all* navigation styling options. I deleted it from my individual screen components, and that fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think all of your name props are incorrect for the two Icon components. I was able to get: `<Icon name="check-circle" />` to display and `<Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" />` to display, but not `<Icon name="md-checkmark-circle" />` or `<Ionicons name="bell" />`.

Here's the searchable list of acceptable icons for Ionicons: https://infinitered.github.io/ionicons-version-3-search/

If you want to use FontAwesome icons, you need to:
`import { FontAwesome } from @expo/vector-icons';` and then use a FontAwesome component with the name prop:
`<FontAwesome name="bell" />`

Also, for the react native elements icon, here is the list of available sets: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html#available-icon-sets

If you look at the font-awesome set, you'll see that 'gear' is not an option, but 'cog' is:
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=gear

Comment: Hi. I tried `<Icon name="check-circle" size ={30} />` along with `<Ionicon name="md-checkmark-circle" />`, and it still did not display.